# variable initialized in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

in this class below there is two Dates StartDate && EndDate i give them Values in
fun check_date() but in fun DateIsChecked() when i try to print the two Values it print null Why?
i try to use lateinit but it did not work

```
companion object {
//Today Date
var today = Calendar.getInstance().time
//Date Format
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")

var calender = Calendar.getInstance()

//Dates Of Plan
var StartDate: java.util.Date? = null
var EndDate: java.util.Date? = null

//Int Value Fore Loop
var i = 0
}

//Check Plan Dates in Database
fun check_date(){
    var Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    Ref.keepSynced(true)//Enable Data Synced
    Ref.child("Plan").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }//End onCancelled
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot){
            for (date in p0.children) {
                var item = date.getValue(Date::class.java)
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 1
                    calender.time = sdf.parse(item!!.Date)
                    EndDate = calender.time
                } else {
                    i = 0
                    calender.time = sdf.parse(item!!.Date)
                    StartDate = calender.time
                }//End else
            }//End For
        }//End onDataChange
    })//End addValueEventListener
}//End

//Chick in Today Date In Date Range And Return The Result: Boolean
open fun DateIsChecked(): Boolean{
    check_date()
    Log.e("Date",today.toString())
    Log.e("Date", StartDate.toString())
    Log.e("Date", EndDate.toString())
    return true
 }
```

Comment: They're only going to be assigned if whatever is in your `Plan` reference actually changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `check_date` method you just added a listener for changing on 'Plan'. so the `onDataChange` method is not called and your `StartDate` and `EndDate` will not get those value until your plan data changes.